# Select element within a list/tuple

Tags: python, list

Hey bit of a beginners question here, I have connected to an imap server using the imaplib and fetched a email, it returns the following:

```
[('1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {62}', "Subject: Gmail is different. Here's what you need to know.\r\n\r\n"), ')']
```

My question is how do I select just the subject element ("Subject: Gmail is...").

I have tried a few combinations but yet to be successful.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a[0][1]
```

where a is the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
    email=[('1 (BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)] {62}', "Subject: Gmail is different. Here's what you need to know.\r\n\r\n"), ')']
    for subj in (subject for element in email for subject in element if subject.startswith("Subject")):
        print subj
""" Output
    Subject: Gmail is different. Here's what you need to know.
"""
```